# Xamarin: override PushAsync on Android navigation

Tags: xamarin, navigation, custom-renderer

I my app, I create a custom navigation rendered, OnPushAsync and PopViewController  are override  and it works on iOS.

```
public class NavRenderer : NavigationRenderer
            {
                protected override async Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page page, bool animated)
                { ...
    }


    public override UIViewController PopViewController(bool animated)
    {
        ....
        return base.PopViewController(false); 
    }
```

Trying to do the same (?) on Android, how can override OnPushAsync and PopViewController?

Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `override` these methods in android renderer to push & pop `Pages`

```
public class NavRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{
    public NavRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page view, bool animated)
    {
        return base.OnPushAsync(view, animated);
    }
    protected override Task<bool> OnPopViewAsync(Page page, bool animated)
    {
        return base.OnPopViewAsync(page, animated);
    }
}
```

These are the equivelent methods in your iOS renderer to push & pop `Controllers`

```
public class NavRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{
    public override void PushViewController(UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
    {
        base.PushViewController(viewController, animated);
    }

    public override UIViewController PopViewController(bool animated)
    {
        return base.PopViewController(animated);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Tx. Do you Know the equivalent to NavigationBar.BarTintColor ,(i use it on iOS nav rendered to change navigation bar color.)

Comment: You can try something like this `((NavigationPage)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.Blue;`